# Obtain case label constant in Roslyn

Tags: c#, switch-statement, roslyn

I'm trying to gather the switch section label constants from a `SwitchStatement` with Roslyn. But while I can see in the Syntax Visualizer that the `CaseSwitchLabelSyntax` has a `Value` property with the corresponding constant and the declared symbol (`SourceLabelSymbol`) has a `SwitchCaseLabelConstant` property, I cannot seem to get that information from what I have in my code.

```
// SwitchStatementSyntax node;
// SemanticModel model;

foreach (var section in node.Sections) {
  foreach (var label in section.Labels) {
    var labelSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(label);
    // Here I'm stuck
  }
}
```

I could probably look whether the `SwitchLabelSyntax` is a `CaseSwitchLabelSyntax` or a `DefaultSwitchLabelSyntax` and cast accordingly. `SourceLabelSymbol` is actually internal, so I cannot access its properties. `model.GetConstantValue(label)` returns `null`.

But given that Roslyn always hands out interfaces I believe that there's a reason for that and wildly casting around feels a bit hacky to me. Is there a better option?

Note: I'm doing this to translate C# syntax into another language. Technically, first into a separate AST that is then converted to text again. Above code is from within a `CSharpSyntaxWalker` and I could probably just store my partially converted `switch` statement away, continue visiting its descendants and build it up piecewise.

But that means having more state, building statements in half a dozen distinct locations which leads to hard-to-read and -follow code. I'd rather avoid it here, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Closest from API is `semanticModel.GetConstantValue` method, but still you need to pass Value node to it like this:

```
section.Labels
       .OfType<CaseSwitchLabelSyntax>()
       .Select(l => semanticModel.GetConstantValue(l.Value))
       .ToArray()
```

As you can see filtering out `CaseSwitchLabelSyntax` is required anyway.